# Change color of JointJS Rappid object (via modifying different instance in the left-nav menu and also modify via Rappid Inspector color picker)?

Tags: jointjs, rappid

I basically want to change the color of a JointJS shape in their RAPPID environment I'm trialing.

**Here is some background on what I have so far and what I want to achieve:**
I have a JointJS shape called ChristmasTree that extends joint.dia.Element.
Basically the svg string that builds this ChristmasTree object is a path of the tree (svg path element), and multiple ornaments on it (4 svg circles/ellipses which have id's and classes that I would assume I can use to modify the colors).

I set some initial values for the ornaments via the style attr inside the svg string.
Once I place that in the left RAPPID menu, the user can drag that one Christmas Tree with red balls on it, yay.
**Question ###1:** 
But I would like to place a 2nd ChristmasTree shape in the left menu without creating another main object that has Green balls... How would I achieve this?
In my below code, **christmas_tree_style_2** should override the .ornament class with 
**'fill': "#00ff00"**, but doesn't (in the left menu, its still red)? 
In fact, **christmas_tree_style_1**, i also tried to override with a Blue ball **'fill': "#0000ff"**, but its still red.
How can I achieve a left-nav override of the shape?

**Question ###2:**
Pretend you help me resolve previous issue. You can drag and drop 2 multiple color ChristmasTree's from the left-menu nav into the main RAPPID content area.
I'd like to now change the colors dynamically through the inspector.
I added a color inspector that shows up in the RAPPID right-nav menu for every element with: 
    'ornament_fill':       { label: 'Color of christmas-tree-ornament's fill',  type: 'color',    group: 'generalinfo', index: 2 }
But not sure how to create an event to dynamically change the color of the ornaments. Any idea? Thanks!

Here is the important part's of the code below.

And also here is an actual working example (but the left-nav initial override and right-nav Inspector color override dont work, hence my 2 questions):
http://armyofda12mnkeys.kissr.com/rappid_christmastree/index.html
(sorry i couldnt find a CDN for rappid.js to add to JSFiddle so it was easier to upload the folder to a site). The applicable files to my question are app.js and rappid-custom-shapes.js.

#

```
//svg for Christmas Tree + its ornaments... will be added to ChristmasTree shape/obj below
var ChristmasTreeSVGstr = "<g class="rotatable"><g class="scalable">
...
<path id="christmastreestrokeid" class="christmastreestroke" ... />

<circle id="ornament1" class="ornament" r="24" cy="350" cx="120"
style="fill:#ff0000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1">...</circle>

<ellipse id="ornament2" class="ornament" rx="30" ry="25" cy="83" cx="231"
style="fill:#ff0000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1">...</circle>

<ellipse id="ornament3" class="ornament" rx="28" ry="38" cy="343" cx="331"
style="fill:#ff0000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1">...</circle>

<ellipse id="ornament4" class="ornament" rx="63" ry="54" cy="238" cx="230"
style="fill:#ff0000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1">...</circle>
</g></g>";
```

#

```
//default Christmas Tree
joint.shapes.basic.ChristmasTree = joint.dia.Element.extend({

            markup: ChristmasTreeSVGstr,
            defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
                type: "basic",              
                                name: 'Initial Christmas Tree label text',                              
                size: {
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20
                },
                attrs: {
                    ".christmastreestroke": {
                        stroke: 'green',
                                                'stroke-width': '100px',
                        'fill-opacity': 1,
                        width: 10,
                        height: 15
                    },
                                        ".ornament": {
                                                'fill': "#00ff00",
                        'fill-opacity': 1                                               
                    },
                                        "#ornament3": {
                                                'fill': "#0000FF",
                                                'stroke': "green",
                                                'stroke-width': '5px',
                                                'fill-opacity': .5          
                    }
                }
            }, joint.dia.Element.prototype.defaults)
});
```

#

```
//RAPPID left menu christmas trees (2 variations of the initial ChristmasTree object, so I need to override some of the colors)
var christmas_tree_style_1 = new joint.shapes.basic.ChristmasTree({
    position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        size: {
            width: 40,
            height: 50
    },
        attr: {
            ".christmastreestroke": {
                stroke: 'green',
                'stroke-width': '100px',
                'fill-opacity': 1,
            },
            ".ornament": {
                    'fill': "#0000ff",
                    'fill-opacity': 1                                               
            },
            "#ornament3": {
                    'fill': "#0000FF",
                    'stroke': "green",
                    'stroke-width': '5px',
                    'fill-opacity': .5          
            }

        }
});
var christmas_tree_style_2 = new joint.shapes.basic.ChristmasTree({
    position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        size: {
            width: 40,
            height: 50
    },
        attr: {
            ".christmastreestroke": {
                stroke: 'blue',
                'stroke-width': '100px',
                'fill-opacity': 1,
            },
            ".ornament": {
                    'fill': "#00ff00",
                    'fill-opacity': 1                                               
            },
            "#ornament3": {
                    'fill': "yellow",
                    'stroke': "yellow",
                    'stroke-width': '5px',
                    'fill-opacity': 1           
            }

        }
});
//add to left menu
stencil.load([christmas_tree_style_1, christmas_tree_style_2], 'customchristmastrees');
```

#

```
//add it to the inspector
function createInspector(cellView) {
    if (!inspector || inspector.options.cellView !== cellView) {

        if (inspector) {
            // Set unsaved changes to the model and clean up the old inspector if there was one.
            inspector.updateCell();
            inspector.remove();
        }
                //if(cellView.$el.hasClass('class')) // certain element should get certain things more in inspector?
                //how to determine different shapes?

        inspector = new joint.ui.Inspector({
            inputs: {
                'name':       { label: 'Name of Christmas Tree',  type: 'text',     group: 'generalinfo', index: 1 },                               

                                'ornament_fill':       { label: 'Color of christmas-tree-ornaments fill',  type: 'color',    group: 'generalinfo', index: 2 },

            },
            groups: {
                generalinfo: { label: 'General Info', index: 1 },                
            },
            cellView: cellView
        });
        $('.inspector-container').html(inspector.render().el);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: this JSFiddle for a non-RAPPID JointJS is best I've seen so far (but still i think not enough to help me since Im trying to do via JointJS's Rappid framework): http://jsfiddle.net/kumilingus/67ajr67r/

Comment: Another guess: add some sort of event like so in createInspector (but this doesn't seem to have a reference to the current instance on the page that it should refer to... How can i grab the current instance related to this inspector, and then apply the colors to all svg .ornament types?):           inspector.on('change:ornament_fill', function(cell, change, opt){
  alert('changed?');
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question #1: you need to remove `style` properties from the markup if you want to change them through the `attr` property on the element. I removed the `fill`, `stroke`, `stroke-width` from the markup:

```
var ChristmasTreeSVGstr = "<g class="rotatable"><g class="scalable">
...
<path id="christmastreestrokeid" class="christmastreestroke" ... />

<circle id="ornament1" class="ornament" r="24" cy="350" cx="120"
style="fill-rule:evenodd;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1">...</circle>

<ellipse id="ornament2" class="ornament" rx="30" ry="25" cy="83" cx="231"
style="fill-rule:evenodd;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1">...</circle>

<ellipse id="ornament3" class="ornament" rx="28" ry="38" cy="343" cx="331"
style="fill-rule:evenodd;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1">...</circle>

<ellipse id="ornament4" class="ornament" rx="63" ry="54" cy="238" cx="230"
style="fill-rule:evenodd;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1">...</circle>
</g></g>";
```

then you can customize the shape as follows:

```
var rb = new joint.shapes.basic.ChristmasTree({
    position: { x: 50, y: 50 },
    size: { width: 100, height: 150 },
    attrs: {
        ".ornament": {
            'fill-opacity': 1,
            stroke: 'pink',
            'stroke-width': 5,
            fill: 'blue'
        }
    }
});
```

[image]

Question #2:

in case you sorted out the issue #1 you can simply sync the values directly with the `attrs`:

```
inspector = new joint.ui.Inspector({
            inputs: {
                'name': { label: 'Name of Christmas Tree', type: 'text', group: 'generalinfo', index: 1 },

                attrs: {
                    '.ornament': {
                        fill: {
                            label: 'Color of christmas-tree-ornaments fill',
                            type: 'color',
                            group: 'generalinfo',
                            index: 2
                        }
                    }
                },

            },
            groups: {
                generalinfo: { label: 'General Info', index: 1 },
            },
            cellView: cellView
        });
```

Comment: awesome thanks @vt. . Curious the color picker shows up as black initially. Is there a way to make it default at the color of the property (even a very manual way to search the svg, get the color of the 1st .ornament and set it as the main color)? The side effect is if you drag a blue, then drag a green (into content area)... then in the content area, click on the blue instance, then click on the green instance, then click back on the blue instance again ... then the color of both instances changes to black since there is no default set I'm guessing.

Comment: colorpicker tries to match with the element color. `blue` doesn't match to any color known for color picker, then it defaults to #000000. chenge the attrs to  ```attrs: {
        ".ornament": {
            'fill-opacity': 1,
            stroke: 'pink',
            'stroke-width': 5,
            fill: '#0000FF'
        }
    }``` and it should change the color picker color as well